# C Program (in OS X) - file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64)

Tags: c, macos, static-libraries, osx-yosemite

I have an assignment in which I have to use a given source code with an included library, namely, libdb_factory.a and libdb_factory32.a (they gave us both x86_64 and ie386 versions).

The first hint of something going wrong is that, when executing lipo -info on **any of them**, I get this:

```
fatal error: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/lipo: archive 
with no architecture specification: libdb_factory32.a 
(can't determine architecture for it)
```

Whenever I try to compile the code with make, I get the following:

```
Compiling
-n
-n Concurent example [..
ld: warning: ignoring file ./lib//libdb_factory.a, file was built for
 archive which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): ./lib//libdb_factory.a
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_db_factory_create_element", referenced from:
  _insert_create in factory-0aefa1.o
  "_db_factory_get_element_name", referenced from:
      _transporter in factory-0aefa1.o
  "_db_factory_get_ready_state", referenced from:
      _transporter in factory-0aefa1.o
  "_db_factory_get_stock", referenced from:
      _transporter in factory-0aefa1.o
      _receiver in factory-0aefa1.o
      _insert_update in factory-0aefa1.o
  "_db_factory_init", referenced from:
      _init_factory in factory-0aefa1.o
  "_db_factory_update_stock", referenced from:
      _transporter in factory-0aefa1.o
      _insert_update in factory-0aefa1.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

The referenced functions are part of the library which is ignored.
I don't have access to a linux machine (unless I use a virtual machine) but I know it works alright on ubuntu 14.04.

Does anyone know what can I do? Any help would be kind appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Static libraries (i.e. the object files within them) compiled for Linux cannot be used on OSX.

The only thing you can do is:

1. Get access to the source and create OSX versions of the libraries.
2. Use a virtual machine to build the code.

Comment: Oh, thank you. That's kind of a bummer, as I cannot access the source (that would equate with cheating in a uni assignment haha).

Comment: @ChrisCS Then you are stuck with 2.  It's a shame they don't give you the freedom to provide a solution on your favourite platform; if they did you could have done it on a Raspberry Pi and literally handed in the work on the physical machine.  Oh well.